# Can we explicitly describe the derived pullback $\mathbf L\pi^* \widetilde M$ for a closed immersion $\pi$ of affine schemes?

Tags: affine-schemes, derived-functors, derived-categories, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $I$ be an ideal of a commutative Noetherian ring $R$. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module and $\widetilde M$ be its associated sheaf on $\text{Spec} (R)$.  We have the closed immersion $\pi: \text{Spec } (R/I)\to \text{Spec} (R)$. My question is: Can we explicitly compute what the derived pullback $\mathbf L\pi^* \widetilde M$ is ?

I am a beginner in derived category methods in algebraic geometry, so your help and guidance is kindly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think if you have a specific module in mind, you can try to find a free resolution of it so you can use the definition of the left derived functor $L\pi^*$ to compute it, i.e., the complex you get after applying (usual) $\pi^*$ is the one you want.